# Always Visable nav bar

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I am on working on a web page to where the nav bar always has to be visable even as the user scrolls down the page. What I am trying to say is that the nav bar should all ways be visable. Does anyone reading know how to do this.

Comment: Yes, what have you tried yourself?...Post your code you have so far

Comment: I did not try anything as I do not know were to start.

Comment: Then I recommend you do a research first. Try and google and use this for a search `nav bar always has to be visable even as the user scrolls down the page` .... can't be simpler and you don't have to sit and wait for someone to find it for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're looking for a basic way to do this, try using fixed positioning like so:

```
<html>
<body>

  <style>
    .navbar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="navbar">
  <!-- Your navbar content here -->
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp) is a link to a tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: For that to work, we need to see more of OP's code, so it is more or less a guess, which we should not do here at SO. Be patient and wait for the OP to add sufficient info before answering

Answer (score -1):

You can use the bootstrap navbar, navbar-fixed-top class to fix the navbar on top.

or you can create a css class like below (if you are using a framework, or you have some css code, make sure that the class names or ids not not repeating in css):

Note: the z-index will make the div overlay on other objects while scrolling.

```css
.mynb{
  posistion:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index : 999;
}
.mywrap
{
width : 100%;
height : auto;
padding-left : 0px;
padding-right : 0px;
padding-bottom : 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

<div class="mywrap">
<div class="mynb">
Nav Bar code here
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For that to work, we need to see more of OP's code, so it is more or less a guess, which we should not do here at SO. Be patient and wait for the OP to add sufficient info before answering